# What is QMetaType::type function replacement in QT6.4.3?

Tags: qt6

I have a code that creates a new object by its type name:

```
class BotModel : public QObject { ... }

using BotPtr = std::shared_ptr<BotModel>;

BotPtr MakeBot(QString type_name)
{
    const std::string full_name = format() << type_name << "*";
        
    const int id = QMetaType::type(full_name.c_str());

    auto metaObject = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(id);
    QObject* p_instance = metaObject->newInstance();

    BotModel* raw_p = qobject_cast<BotModel*>(p_instance);

    BotPtr bot(raw_p);

    bot->onCreated();

    return bot;
}
```

but in QT6.4 I started to get warnings (with MSVC):

```
warning C4996: 'QMetaType::type': was declared deprecated
warning C4996: 'QMetaType::metaObjectForType': was declared deprecated
```

what is the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QMetaType::fromName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetatype.html#fromName)

`auto metaObject = QMetaType::fromName(full_name.c_str()).metaObject();`